# vb.net modify column in CSV file

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a CSV file with many rows in which I need to update/replace column four's value using VB.NET. There are no headers on the columns so the loop can start on row one.

> infile.csv
>    "value1","value2","value3","value4"

After much googling, there are lots of examples on how to read and write CSV files, but none quite what is needed. I know there are multiple ways to accomplish this task, but a requirement is that it's done with VB.NET. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Final code ported from Marco's C# answer

```
    Private Sub CSVmod(ByVal strFileName As String, ByVal newFileName As String)

    Dim strLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(strFileName)
    Dim strList As New List(Of String)
    Dim strReplace As String = "test"

    For Each line In strLines
        Dim strValues As String() = line.Split(",")
        If (strValues.Length = 14) Then
            strValues(3) = strReplace

            strList.Add(String.Join(",", strValues))
        End If

    Next

    File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, strList.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I can write it only in C#.
I think you won't find many problems to convert to VB.NET.
Here is my code:

```
private void SubstFile(string filename, string newFileName)
{
    // Reading all rows of the file
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // For every row I split it with commas
        string[] values = line.Split(',');
        // Check to have 4 values
        if (values.Length == 4)
        {
            // Substitute fourth value
            values[3] = "new value";
            // Add modified row to list
            list.Add(String.Join(",", values));
        }
    }
    // Save list to new file
    File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, list.ToArray());
}
```

---

**VB.NET version:**

```
Private Sub SubstFile(filename As String, newFileName As String)
    ' Reading all rows of the file
    Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filename)

    Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    For Each line As String In lines
        ' For every row I split it with commas
        Dim values As String() = line.Split(","c)
        ' Check to have 4 values
        If values.Length = 4 Then        
            ' Substitute fourth value
            values(3) = "new value"
            ' Add modified row to list
            list.Add(String.Join(",", values))
        End If
    Next
    ' Save list to new file
    File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, list.ToArray())
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of reading all Lines you can use [Textfieldparser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) in VB.Net. But otherwise than that I don't know if you can edit only a field without rewriting the whole file

Comment: @Nicholas: `TextFieldParser` is inside ` Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace, while solution I provided is valid in every language (VB.NET, C#, ASP.NET). Parsing that file is too easy to need anther class to do taht, don't you think? :)

Comment: Use http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ to convert the code.

Comment: TextFieldParser is better because CSV files still support String Values with commas in them (usually surrounded by quotations).  This code will screw up in those situations.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  Thanks for the awesome site Olivier (would have been great bout an hour ago though :-\ already have it ported -- *end result posted above*), This will be nice to use in the future.

Comment: @user825315: did you see my VB version? ;)

Comment: @Marco sure did, your answer has been marked as 'Accepted'. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: @Marco you can also use the `TextFieldParser` in C# if you like :) But I mentioned it becaus the question was for vb. And it supports the RFC spec (multiline fields and so on..)

Comment: @Nicholas: yes, but I have to _import_ Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.. and I really don't like this ;) Anyway, your point was correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Use python....one line of code

df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).